# Why is the API Gateway corrupting my binary file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway acting as a proxy to a backend service:

```
{
  "apiKeySource": "HEADER", 
  "name": "-", 
  "createdDate": 1513820260, 
  "binaryMediaTypes": [
      "application/zip", 
      "application/octet-stream"
  ], 
  "endpointConfiguration": {
      "types": [
          "EDGE"
      ]
  }, 
  "id": "-"
```

}

The integration definition is here:

```
{
  "integrationResponses": {
      "200": {
          "responseTemplates": {
              "application/json": null
          }, 
          "statusCode": "200"
      }
  }, 
  "passthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH", 
  "timeoutInMillis": 29000, 
  "uri": "http://${stageVariables.backend}:7000/{proxy}", 
  "connectionType": "INTERNET", 
  "httpMethod": "ANY", 
  "cacheNamespace": "iv06s3", 
  "type": "HTTP_PROXY", 
  "requestParameters": {
      "integration.request.path.proxy": "method.request.path.proxy", 
      "integration.request.header.X-Source-IP": "context.identity.sourceIp"
  }, 
  "cacheKeyParameters": [
      "method.request.path.proxy"
  ]
 }
```

I have an endpoint that generates a Zip file on the fly and returns it to the requester.

When I access the endpoint directly, the file is fine. When I access it via the API Gateway, it gets corrupted.

The corruption takes the form of bytes in the original file being converted to `0xEFBFBD`. This is the [UTF-8 'replacement character'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character).

My request has `Accept` set to `application/zip` and the response has `Content-Type: application/zip`.

My expectation is that the API Gateway should recognize this as a binary media type and leave the file alone, but it seems pretty clear that it's processing it as text content.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you enable binary media type for your API ? ( ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html )

Comment: I did. It's shown in the RestAPI description in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Setting the  "Binary Media Type" to "multipart/form-data" resolved a similar issue for me.
See here: [AWS Api Gateway as a HTTP Proxy is currupting binary uploaded image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725317/aws-api-gateway-as-a-http-proxy-is-currupting-binary-uploaded-image-files)

Comment: Thanks, you saved me!