# AWS Api Gateway as a HTTP Proxy is currupting binary uploaded image files

Tags: amazon-web-services, paperclip, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have a ruby on rails app that takes an image file, "attaches it to a member", and uploads it to s3. When I use insomnia and POST directly to the app ... **it works**, however when I use the exact same endpoint behind AWS Api Gateway, the image is corrupt and not viewable.

---

**Here is the comparison of the requests.**

- LEFT = directly posted to the rails app
- RIGHT = through api gateway

https://www.diffchecker.com/wwUmpB5W

Something I noticed, is that the paperclip gem is running different commands. It's evident that paperclip realized that the file is not an image when being passed through API gateway.

---

**Here are some potentially relevant screenshots**

[image: method execution]
[image: integration request]
[image: api gateway settings]

---

**Here is the rails code:**

```
def create
  logger.info 'upload_attachment_api_general_v1'
  logger.info params
  logger.info request.env
  @file = current_merchant.members.find(params[:member_id]).attachments.new(file: params[:file], label: params[:label])
  if params[:file] && @file.save
    render json: @file
  else
    render json: @file.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out. The content type is NOT an `image/png` ... the content type is `multipart/form-data`

[image: multipart]

Comment: Thank you!  I don't know how, but this does indeed do the trick for PNG images.  It also explains why `image/*` wasn't working for me, but `*/*` was working.  It still doesn't work for .ICO images (such as `favicon.ico`), but nothing else has, so I'm going to chalk it up to API Gateway quirkiness.

Comment: One quick note, that you still need to deploy the api again AFTER you've made the settings adjustment.  That may be obvious to others, but it wasn't to me.